# Problems linking C library with C++ wxWidgets program

Tags: c++, c, wxwidgets

Lately, I've been experimenting with creating a library in C (somewhat a libtar clone) that helps users manipulate *sarf* archives (a custom archive format of mine).

Along with the library there comes a command line program that implements all the library's features. Adds file to archive, extracts, removes, lists all files. It works pretty good.

I decided to create a gui program for desktop as well, with wxWidgets in C++ (using also my library).

I knew that C libraries were usable in C++ code but you only needed to implement them like that:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <my_c_lib.h>
}
```

So, I started developing that C++ gui app. But quite to my surprise it didn't worked very well.

In the c++ app, random characters appear in the filename that they don't in the command line app causing of course problems to the app.

I found out that these characters were appearing only when I was calling `target_link_libraries` in CMakeLists.txt to link the program with my library and wxWidgets. If comment this line, rebuild, run, everything appears fine.

- I'm using MacOS Big Sur
- My OS's locale is Greek (el_GR.UTF-8)
- wxWidgets (3.1.5) installed from [brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/wxwidgets)

---

#### Examples:

- [This is how the program works with C and without wxWidgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bsqw.jpg)
- [This is how the program works with C++17 and wxWidgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFK4F.jpg)

---

C++ code for gui app [here](https://github.com/billvog/arman)
and library [here](https://github.com/billvog/sarf).

Comment: What OS? Each one has a very different linker. BSD is classic, Linux is sane, Mac is opinionated, and Windows is ... Windows.

Comment: MacOS Big Sur (also I have the M1 chip)

Comment: Maybe related: `extern "C" {`  `#include <my_c_lib.h>`
`}` is _not_ the polite way of writing `my_c_lib.h`. Add the linkage instructions _inside_ `my_c_lib.h` instead if you want it to be useful for C++ programmers too.

Comment: You seem to ignore compiler warnings, which is not generally wise ( I am referring to `fread` retrurn value ignore). I am trying to get this working on linux due to `struct stat` being defined a bit differently

Comment: After dealing with the issues presented (I am assuming that they were due to me being on linux (however for `std::sort`, `<algorithm>` should be included)), I have tried recreating the bug and failed. If you could add an example to the error that would be helpful.

Comment: @BasilhsBogiatzhs, what is you locale settings? Are you using US version of OS? What is wxWidgets version? Did you compile it yourself? Using configure or `CMake-thingy`? Are you using UNICODE or ANSI build of the library?

Comment: @Igor, I added all these information in my post. However, I didn't really understood the UNICODE or ANSI question. I'm build the library with CMake, if that helps. Here is the [CMakeLists file](https://github.com/billvog/sarf/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: "My OS's locale is Greek" What is it *exactly*? What is the output of `locale`?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The output from `locale` command says `el_GR.UTF-8`

Comment: Great. Now you need to analyse the exact bytes that the program outputs. Redirect the output to a file file and look at it through a hex editor, or pipe it through a program such as  `od -c`. What appears in place of those question marks?

Comment: By the way you should only wrap your own code in `extern "C"` `#include` directives with system headers should generally go outside of the `extern "C" { ... }` block (unless they themselves are missing `extern "C" { ... }` which for the most part doesn't happen). This is unlikely to be the reason of your problem though.

Comment: I did that, I took a screenshot see it [here](https://imgur.com/a/il1jSjk).

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text, add this information to your post as text.

Comment: I don't know where these characters could possibly come from. Your best bet is probably using a debugger and watching your string variables.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the results you show. `Arman path/to/archive` doesn't even produce output for me, apart from opening the manager. Is the code you run in the example the same as the one on github?